# Logging into an expressjs app with CORS

Tags: ajax, node.js, cordova, cors

I have expressjs sitting on a nodejs server and I have a client side cordova app making ajax requests to certain routes.

This is fine until I need to make a POST request to login using passportjs, there is a 302 redirect that takes place so I get this `302 Moved Temporarily` when making this call

```
$('body').on('submit', '#logIn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://mydomain.io:3300/login",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(response){
            alert('succeeded!');
            console.log(response);
            alert(response);
        },
        failure: function(message){
            alert("failed");
            console.log(message);
            alert(message);
        }
    });

});
```

So my question is how is it possible using CORS to login to the app using client side ajax?

Comment: I don't think CORS is your problem here.  You shouldn't login via AJAX with passport

Comment: I feel like this is not ideal, but I cant think of any other way since the app is expressjs based and now that I am converting it into a cordova/phonegap app this is the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is not your problem here.

Passport wants to redirect your user (based on the values you've passed to `passport.authenticate`).  For instance:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                      failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Passport will tell the browser to redirect to `/` or `/login` by returning a `302`.  You can remove the redirect by removing the second parameter to `passport.authenticate`:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));
```

This will call `next()` on successful authentication (and return `401` otherwise).

The examples here use `FacebookStrategy`, but it works with any strategy.

Comment: Oh wow that makes sense, I really didn't think the whole process through. Trying it out now :)

Comment: I will of course, trying it out because I may have some basic question, I am using a local strategy first and not an oauth facebook strategy (not for now at least) do I just strip the successRedirect call back and have the post method like this `app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login');`?

Comment: Okay I got the 401 but it came up `401 Unauthorized` I will accept this and do my research on that error. Thanks